# Wireless Keyboard: SHIFT-P suddenly not working

Tags: keyboard

**(This question is NOT about Macbook Pro keyboards. It is about an Apple Wireless Keyboard)**

I'm using an old Apple Wireless Keyboard (can't find model number - it's the white and clear plastic model).

Yesterday the SHIFT-P (capital 'P') functionality suddenly stopped working. I didn't spill anything or otherwise mess with the keyboard (that I am aware of).

The "p" key works fine but in order to type a capital 'P', I need to set the caps lock. I looked at the 'keyboard viewer' and SHIFT-P doesn't trigger an event. No other keys appear to be affected.

Anyone seen this before?

**UPDATE** ok, so it's the left SHIFT key which is failing with the letter "P" but the right SHIFT key works fine with it. Weird. I understand total hardware failure but why would the left SHIFT key only fail with the letter "P"?

*(the irony here: I am using the wireless keyboard because my MacBook Pro laptop battery swelled up and knocked out the Y, U, I, O keys. I replaced the battery but that didn't fix the keyboard issue)*

Comment: @Allan - not a duplicate of that question. That question is about Macbook Pro keyboards. This question involves an Apple Wireless Keyboards.Please read my question again. Thanks.

Comment: It’s a canonical question about **all** keyboards - external keyboards are addressed in the question/answer.   This question is no different from the scenarios presented.